# sliding window on subarray sum (positive integers)

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, sliding-window

I have an array of positive integers of size n and a secret number which is equal to the sum of at least one (contiguous) subarray of nonzero size.

I can query if a number is greater or equal to the secret number in O(1).

Using O(n) sliding window, are there any cases which will result in the wrong answer?

```
    <precalculations>
        int lb = prefixSum[high-1]+1; //lower bound
        int ub = prefixSum[high]; //upper bound
        int lindex=0, rindex=1, test;
        while (rindex < prefixSum.length && lb!= ub){
            test= prefixSum[rindex]-prefixSum[lindex];
            if(checkSecret(test)){
                //larger or equal to secret, shrink window
                ub = min(ub,test);
                lindex++;
            } else {
                lb = max(lb, test);
                rindex++;
            }
        }
        return ub;
```

Comment: start from the naive approach... what have you got so far?

Comment: what do you mean? The main point of me asking is because I can't think of any testcases that will give the wrong answer, not because I can't figure out how to do sliding window

Comment: you might want to mention what result the procedure is *supposed* to produce.

Comment: Checking whether your code is correct is probably outside the scope of this site.  The way to tell whether your algorithm is correct is to try it on some test cases, and then prove it correct.  It's not clear what the task is -- it's not clear what the desired output is.  It's not clear what is meant by "Using O(n) sliding window".  This makes it hard to tell what you are asking, or what your approach is.  Can you [edit] your question to address these issues?